# How to perform selective removal based on value from a list in TCL?

Tags: tcl

Considering a list like {100 169 144 289}, what is the best way to remove odd squares 169,289 as in the example list here?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method is to filter the list. Depending on the nature of the condition, the main techniques are `lsearch -all -inline` (possibly with `-not`) for something that can be expressed as a string pattern, and `lmap` for the rest. In your case, we can do:

```
set filtered [lmap x $input {
    if {$x & 1} then continue else {set x}
}]
```

The trick here is that a `continue` in the body of an `lmap` *skips* the adding of the value to the output list, and `set x` reads the value of `x`. The result is to skip all odd numbers (because `$x & 1` is an expression that is true when `x` holds an odd number) and otherwise to add to the list. The expression can be as complex as you want. (To overwrite, just do `set input [lmap ...]` instead of `set filtered [lmap ...]`. Keep them separate when testing.)